# Download and save an HttpRequestMessage C#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

In my WP8.1 Silverlight app, I want to download a file and save it to an isolated storage. The downloading is OK, but how I can save it ?

For the downloading, I use this :

```
 var HttpClientDownloadFile = new Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient();

        Windows.Web.Http.HttpRequestMessage request = new Windows.Web.Http.HttpRequestMessage(Windows.Web.Http.HttpMethod.Get, new Uri(downloadUrl));
        request.Headers.Add("Range", "bytes=0-");

        // Hook up progress handler.
        Progress<HttpProgress> progressCallback = new Progress<HttpProgress>(OnSendRequestProgress);
        var tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        Windows.Web.Http.HttpResponseMessage response = await HttpClientDownloadFile.SendRequestAsync(request).AsTask(tokenSource.Token, progressCallback);
```

If I run the debug, in response.content I have my download. Now, I want to save it to the isolated storage. How can I do that ? Should I use an stream ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Convert your response to stream and write it to file

```
using (var fileStream = await this.storageFile.OpenFileAsync(fileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
{      
    await stream.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
}
```

Comment: Should I do something like that : `using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                Windows.Web.Http.HttpResponseMessage response = await HttpClientDownloadFile.SendRequestAsync(request).AsTask(tokenSource.Token, progressCallback);
            }` ?